# Книги по написанию компиляторов

Tags: c, книги, компилятор

Посоветуйте Русские книги по созданию компиляторов на языке Си, искал, именно на языке Си не могу найти.

Comment: Созданием компиляторов занимаются люди уровня практически близкому к научным исследователям. Возьмите исходники gcc, почитайте комментарии в них - отличное пособие.

Comment: Русские и именно с большой буквы? Нет таких, вроде. Из переводов есть Dragon Book

Comment: Можно начать с книги дракона.

Comment: Язык на котором писать не имеет никакого значения, изучайте общую теорию лексических и синтаксических анализаторов. потом уже собственно компиляторов. потом изучаете ассемблер выбранной для компиляции платформы, что бы владеть им на уровне профессионала, после этого можно делать собственно компилятор, т.е. программу которая будет генерировать машинный код.

Comment: [Драгонбук, она же "Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструменты"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Компиляторы:_принципы,_технологии_и_инструменты). А вот язык не имеет значения, все принципы Вам придется переносить на код самостоятельно.

Comment: Насчёт компиляторов уже всё сказали. Если это не огорчило, посмотрите, например, исходники [TCC](https://bellard.org/tcc/) или [PicoC](https://github.com/zsaleeba/picoc)

Comment: @PinkTux, он хочет компилятор на си писать, а не компилятор для си. Зачем выбирать для примера язык с одним из самых сложных (если вообще не самым сложным) синтаксическим разбором?

Comment: @gormih, то же самое, что в комментарии выше. Зачем gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "Основы конструирования компиляторов" В.А.Серебряков, М.П.Галочкин
- "Конструирование компиляторов для цифровых вычислительных машин" Грис, Д.
- "Теория синтаксического анализа, перевода и компиляции." Ахо
  А., Ульман Дж.  Том 1 и 2.